# C++ function loop and if statements not working

Tags: c++

So i am trying to make a betting game. A player has to enter a number between 0 and 100, and it cant be any higher or any lower. This is what i have so far.

```
int Player_Money = 100;
int Computer_Money = 100;



int Check(int &b) { //b here would be Player_Money
    int Player_Bet = 0;
    bool Exit_Loop = false;

    cout << "Please Enter A Number Between 0 and " << b;

    while (!Exit_Loop) {
        cin >> Player_Bet;
        if (Player_Bet <= 0) {
            cout << "The Amount That You Have Entered Is To Low.\n";
        }

        else if (Player_Bet > b) {
            cout << "The Amount That You Have Entered Is Too High.\n";
        }

        if (Player_Bet > 0) {
            if (Player_Bet < b) {
                Exit_Loop = true;
                if (Player_Bet = b) {
                    cout << "You Have Gone All In!\n";
                    Exit_Loop = true;
                }
            }

        }
        return Player_Bet;
    }
}
```

And when i try to do Check(Variable); and this is what happens.

If its to low, it will say its to low, and exits the loop.
If its to high, it will say you have entered a number to high. Then exit.
If its within range, it says you have gone all in, return 100, and exit.

What i would like to know is:

*how to make the loop cycle correctly and how to make the function return the right number.

Comment: Your return statement is inside the loop, it will return from `Check()` after the first execution straight away. Also: When `(Player_Bet <= 0)` or `(Player_Bet > b)` you never set `Exit_Loop = true`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First check if `Player_bet` greter than `0` and less than `b`. Check if equal `b` after.

```
int Player_Money = 100;
int Computer_Money = 100;

int Check(int &b) { //b here would be Player_Money
    int Player_Bet = 0;
    bool Exit_Loop = false;

    cout << "Please Enter A Number Between 0 and " << b;

    while (!Exit_Loop) {
        cin >> Player_Bet;
        if (Player_Bet <= 0) {
            cout << "The Amount That You Have Entered Is To Low.\n";
        }
        else if (Player_Bet > b) {
            cout << "The Amount That You Have Entered Is Too High.\n";
        }
        else if (Player_Bet > 0 && Player_Bet < b ) {
            Exit_Loop = true;
        }
        else /* if (Player_Bet == b) */ {
            cout << "You Have Gone All In!\n";
            Exit_Loop = true;
        }       
    }
    return Player_Bet;
}
```

Comment: You sure? This still contains the useless `while()` loop with the return statement *inside* the loop.

Answer (score 0):

If its within range, it says you have gone all in, return 100, and exit

change if (Player_Bet = b) by if (Player_Bet == b) because = sets b to Player_Bet and == is to compare values.

If you don't want it to exit before having a in range value, move return Player_Bet; out of the while loop

Answer (score 0):

One of the main problems I see in the code segment you posted is that you have your `return` statement *within* your `while loop`. So no matter the value of `Player_Bet` if will always return and end the method at the end of the first iteration....in other words, if will never *actually* loop.

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues in your code:

1. You are using = to compare, you should use ==
2. You are making redundant compare.
3. Your exit loop has no meaning since you will always return.

This will suits you better. However be aware that doing while(true) is generally not a good idea.

```
while (true) {
   cin >> Player_Bet;
   if (Player_Bet <= 0) {
       cout << "The Amount That You Have Entered Is To Low.\n";
   } else if (Player_Bet > b) {
       cout << "The Amount That You Have Entered Is Too High.\n";
   } else {
       if (Player_Bet == b) {
           cout << "You Have Gone All In!\n";
       }
       return Player_Bet;
   }
}
```